# plotly html embedded in shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, plotly

I have generated few plots using `plotly` and saved them as offline html (I don't want to generate them live as it would take so long to generate them in the background). The followings are the two plots taken from `plotly` site and I saved them as html.

```
#Graph 1
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, file="zoo.html")


#Graph 2
x <- c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C')
y <- c(20, 14, 23)
text <- c('27% market share', '24% market share', '19% market share')
data <- data.frame(x, y, text)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'bar', text = text,
             marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                           line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                                       width = 1.5))) %>%
  layout(title = "January 2013 Sales Report",
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = ""))
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, file="product.html")
```

I have written some `shiny` codes that can show html output from `Rmarkdown` but not the html that i generated from `plotly` above. Note that the first choice(sample) in the `selectInput()` is what I generated from default `Rmarkdown` html and that works. I also generated multiple `rmarkdown` html and I could also switch between htmls in the `shiny` app but not for `plotly` html.

```
ui= fluidPage(
  titlePanel("opening web pages"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId='test',label=1,choices=c("sample","zoo","product"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("inc")
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return(includeHTML(paste0("file:///C:/Users/home/Documents/",input$test,".html")))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({getPage()})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe for this - also have a look at `addResourcePath`:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("opening web pages"),
  sidebarPanel(selectInput(
    inputId = 'test',
    label = 1,
    choices = c("sample", "zoo", "product")
  )),
  mainPanel(htmlOutput("inc"))
)

server = function(input, output) {
  myhtmlfilepath <- getwd() # change to your path
  addResourcePath('myhtmlfiles', myhtmlfilepath)

  getPage <- function() {
    return(tags$iframe(src = paste0("myhtmlfiles/", input$test, ".html"), height = "100%", width = "100%", scrolling = "yes"))
  }

  output$inc <- renderUI({
    req(input$test)
    getPage()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```